# Get the variable associated with a JPanel component from a component array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, components, class-instance-variables

Say I have a JPanel with buttons (and other things) as components and I make an array of those components as such:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

JButton btn1 = new JButton();
JButton btn2 = new JButton();
JButton btn3 = new JButton();

panel.add(btn1);
panel.add(btn2);
panel.add(btn3);

Component[] things = panel.getComponents();`
```

How can I get the names of the variables associated with the components in the array?  I'm looking to grab "btn1", "btn2", etc...

```
for (int i = 0; i < things.length; i++) {

*I need this to return the names of the variables associated with the components*

}
```

Comment: Why do you think you need the variable name of each button. Sounds like a design problem to me.

Comment: It may very well be a design problem, though it may not.  I'm trying to implement a user interface with formatted JPanels.  The panels already have JButtons and I'm trying to create a method that will assign certain actions to certain buttons (in the main method), or also create buttons and assign actions to the buttons when the JPanel is instantiated.  This is a perplexing problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using reflection:

```
Field[] fields = panel.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field f : fields) {
            if (f.getType().equals(JButton.class)) {
                System.out.println(f.getName());
            }
        }
```